# CSS design in old IE browsers

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Why does the background and the menu buttons shape not display correctly in IE versions < 11? The page looks ok in Chrome, IE 11, etc.

http://www.kine-stammheim.ch/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Websites breaking in one type but working in another is usually related to illegal usage of HTML or CSS. Some browser allow you to do something you're not really allowed to do meanwhile others don't.

Use the [w3.org HTML validation service](http://validator.w3.org/) to find errors on your website (HTML), you can take look at your results [here](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.kine-stammheim.ch%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0), you'll see that you got some errors on your website.

You can also use the [w3.org CSS validation service](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) to find errors on your website (CSS), you can take a look at your results [here](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.kine-stammheim.ch%2F&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en).

You will see that your website has over 100 errors in the CSS; this is probably the cause of your problem. Fix your HTML and CSS and your website should render just fine.

Also check available tables to see which CSS and HTML attributes work on all browsers, some don't, yet.

You could use the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) to check the compatibility of browsers. Let's, for example check the [-moz-](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance) attribute you're using in your CSS;

```
Browser                     Lowest version    Support of
Internet Explorer           ---               ---
Firefox (Gecko)             1.0 (1.0)         -moz-appearance Not fully supported
Opera (Presto)              ---               ---
Safari | Chrome | WebKit    3.0 | 1.0 | 522   -webkit-appearance
```

You'll see that you'll have problems on certain browsers, like Internet Explorer.

You can also check the table [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance#Browser_compatibility).

Note that compatibility issues are mainly related to HTML5 and CSS3, which are the newest versions.

Comment: I fixed the background issue. The round corner issue however seems not to be so easy for old IEs...

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that you're using CSS3 properties, those properties not have support in all versions of the browsers and in some cases need for special prefixers.

Check this link http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp

For example your background made with css has this prefixes:

```
-webkit-linear-gradient

-moz-linear-gradient

-ms-linear-gradient

-o-linear-gradient
```

Review this here -webkit-linear-gradient(

Answer (score 2):

here is your background definition for #main:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #DBDBDB, #FFFFFF) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

IE don't understand the -moz prefix

you need the complete definition in order to support the other browser families, e.g.:

```
background: rgb(69,72,77);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(69,72,77,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(69,72,77,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(69,72,77,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(69,72,77,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(69,72,77,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(69,72,77,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
```

Look at: https://www.google.de/search?q=vendor+specific+CSS+extensions